# Trigonometric Equation Problem

Tags: calculus

I need to solve the following equation: $(-12\cos^2(x)-2\cos(x)+3)(-\sin(x))=0$ on the interval $(0,2\pi)$

I found 3 out of 5 solutions which are the following: $\pi, \arccos\left(\frac{-1-\sqrt{37}}{12}\right) \mbox{ and } \arccos\left(\frac{\sqrt{37}-1}{12}\right)$

Can someone help me find the 2 other solutions

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you believe there are 5 solutions? You have a trigonometric polynomial of degree 3 limited to $\,(0,2\pi)\,$, so three solutions look good for me...unless you've some further info.

Comment: I see on the graph that there exists two additional solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $\cos x=\cos (2\pi-x)$. So if $\alpha$ is a solution, then so is $2\pi-\alpha$.
So you have $\pi, \arccos\left(\frac{-1-\sqrt{37}}{12}\right), \arccos\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{37}}{12}\right),2\pi-\arccos\left(\frac{-1-\sqrt{37}}{12}\right),2\pi-\arccos\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{37}}{12}\right)$
5 solutions, as required.

Comment: @user43418: You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

your answer is here,

take a look at:

[wolfram alpha gives this answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-12%2acos%28x%29%5E2%20-2%2acos%28x%29%20%2b%203%29%28-sin%28x%29%29%20=%200)

Comment: but copy all of the thing, sorry (I should tell it beforehand)